# When to Marshal.ReleaseComObject in Office when passing objects as a parameter?

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, outlook-addin

I want to get my memory management of Office COM objects right especially in my classes.

**Example**
Outlook addin looks at the current selection and gets the 1st selected item.
For example

```
  Dim oSel as Outlook.Selection
  Dim oMailItem as Outlook.MailItem

  oSel = DirectCast(oExp.Selection, Outlook.Selection)
  oMailItem = DirectCast(oSel.Item(i), Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim newClass as New OtherClass

  newClass.methodInAnotherClass(oMailItem)
```

if oMailItem is passed with a  byVal parameter to a new class for example like this:

**Another Class' Method**

```
Public sub methodInAnotherClass(byval aMailItem as Outlook.MailItem)

     Dim myMailItem as Outlook.MailItem = Nothing

     myMailItem = aMailItem


End Sub
```

myMailItem may be passed within this class byval to other methods as well.

My understanding is that while I might have a number of .NET variables of this mailItem all these variables reference the same run-time callable wrapper (RCW).  Thus in the above example calling

```
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myMailItem)
```

Is the same as calling

```
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oMailItem)
```

And as such I need to make sure I call it on one after I am finished using it on both.

If now I am creating a small library of methods for my Outlook addin what convention should I follow.  Take for example this;

I pass an Outlook.Selection to my library methods.  My understanding is my library should not call Marshal.ReleaseComObject on the selection but if for example within this selection there is a mailitem and my Library initializes this, then my library needs to call Marshal.ReleaseComObject on this mail item.

I am not sure if you will understand my words so here it is in code form

```
  Dim oSel as Outlook.Selection

  oSel = DirectCast(oExp.Selection, Outlook.Selection)

  Dim newClass as New OtherClass

  newClass.methodInAnotherClass(oSel)

  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSel)
```

Then in the other class method

```
Public sub methodInAnotherClass(byval aSelection as Outlook.Selection)

     Dim myMailItem as Outlook.MailItem = Nothing
     myMailItem = DirectCast(aSelection.Item(i), Outlook.MailItem)


     'Do alot of things

      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myMailItem)

End Sub
```

Am I on the right track people?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx